# Javascript - Clone a div after user input on quantity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to clone a div after a user puts in the amount of divs to be cloned.  User will put in a number (say 3) and the function will create three `group-container` divs.  The prompt works, but nothing happens after that.  Seems pretty simple but it's evading me.  Is my logic incorrect?  Obviously my programming skills are very new.

1. I create a function that has the input (groupInput)
2. Create a for loop to reiterate the following instruction
3. The for loop will clone `group-container` as many times as `i<groupInput`

   ```
   function addGroup() {
     var groupInput = prompt("How many groups?  1-100");
     for(i=0; i<groupInput; i++){
       var group = document.getElementById("group-container");
       var clone = group.cloneNode(true);
       group.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
     }
   }
   ```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

**Updated**

Thanks for the suggestions, I get I should use class for this now.

I did get it to work with the ID in jsfiddle (not sure why it's not in my html), but now with the class it's not:  https://jsfiddle.net/waynebunch/c5sw5dxu/.  getElementsByClassName is valid right?

Comment: This looks like the wrong approach to solve who knows what. You'll end up with multiple nodes in the dom all with the same `id`. That smells funny.

Comment: Actually it seems to be working here: https://jsfiddle.net/briosheje/70wn3oah/ (that's terrible though, don't duplicate ids!)

Comment: @CrescentFresh Got it, will change

Comment: @briosheje Yea that's weird, I didn't run it in JS at first.  It's not working in my html though.  I know my links to the js are correct as the popup works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the group declaration outside of the for loop so the clone remains the same throughout the loop.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwenay5x/)

```
function addGroup() {
   var groupInput = prompt("How many groups?  1-100");
   var group = document.getElementById("group-container");
   for(i=0; i<groupInput; i++){     
     var clone = group.cloneNode(true);
     group.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `prompt()` method probably returns the correct number, but with type set to String. Instead try

```
parseInt(groupInput)
```

To convert the value to a number, which should allow the for loop to execute properly.

Comment: The for loop should still work if you give it a string

Comment: You're right, stupid of me to forget that. Either way, I think it's good practice to convert it to an integer for safety.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below might work once you get your quantity in from a prompt or text input.

```
var doc = document;

var input = prompt("Please enter your qty", "0");
if (input != null) {
    for (i = 0; i < input; i++) { 
        var elem = doc.createElement('div');
        elem.className = 'group-container';
    }
}
```